# Replace canonical URLs in product pages

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions, canonical

I am trying to manually set the canonical URL on product pages.

To do so, I extended the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` class and modified the `_prepareLayout` method:

```
class FKoessler_MyProduct_Block_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
{
  protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
      $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/breadcrumbs');
      $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
      if ($headBlock) {
          $product = $this->getProduct();
          $title = $product->getMetaTitle();
          if ($title) {
              $headBlock->setTitle($title);
          }
          $keyword = $product->getMetaKeyword();
          $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
          if ($keyword) {
              $headBlock->setKeywords($keyword);
          } elseif ($currentCategory) {
              $headBlock->setKeywords($product->getName());
          }
          $description = $product->getMetaDescription();
          if ($description) {
              $headBlock->setDescription( ($description) );
          } else {
              $headBlock->setDescription(Mage::helper('core/string')->substr($product->getDescription(), 0, 255));
          }
          if ($this->helper('catalog/product')->canUseCanonicalTag()) {

              $params = array('_ignore_category' => true);

              /////////////////////////////////////// START WITH CANONICAL
              $cannURL = $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, $params);

              $productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

              $tmpStoreCode = false;
              $tmpStoreCode =  Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();

              $expCatIdStore = false;

              switch ($tmpStoreCode) {
                  case 'paris_french':
                      $expCatIdStore = 2;
                      break;
                  case 'nimes_french':
                      $expCatIdStore = 3;
                      break;
                  case 'niort_french':
                      $expCatIdStore = 6;
                      break;
              }

              if ($expCatIdStore && $productId) {

                  $headBlock->removeItem('canonical');
                  if ($tmpStoreCode === 'paris_french') {
                      $cannURL = str_replace('/paris', '', $cannURL);
                      $headBlock->addLinkRel('canonical', $cannURL);
                  } elseif ($tmpStoreCode === 'nimes_french') {
                      $cannURL = str_replace('/nimes', '', $cannURL);
                      $headBlock->addLinkRel('canonical', $cannURL);
                  } elseif ($tmpStoreCode === 'niort_french') {
                      $cannURL = str_replace('/niort', '', $cannURL);
                      $headBlock->addLinkRel('canonical', $cannURL);
                  } else {
                      $headBlock->addLinkRel('canonical', $cannURL);
                  }
              }
              //////////////////////////////////// END WITH CANONICAL

          }
      }

      return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View::_prepareLayout();
  }

}
```

The canonical URL that I add manually is properly set.

The problem is that product pages now have two canonical links. The default one linking to the product page and the custom one that I added.

How can I replace the default canonical link instead of adding a new one?

EDIT:

Adding some debugging output, I notice that Magento enters both `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View::_prepareLayout` and `FKoessler_MyProduct_Block_Product_View::_prepareLayout` multiple times:

```
[Fri Jun 12 11:15:30.544350 2015] [:error] [pid 9972] [client 127.0.0.1:34926] Entering FKoessler_MyProduct_Block_Product_View::_prepareLayout
[Fri Jun 12 11:15:30.552185 2015] [:error] [pid 9972] [client 127.0.0.1:34926] Entering FKoessler_MyProduct_Block_Product_View::_prepareLayout
[Fri Jun 12 11:15:30.552931 2015] [:error] [pid 9972] [client 127.0.0.1:34926] Entering FKoessler_MyProduct_Block_Product_View::_prepareLayout
[Fri Jun 12 11:15:30.553767 2015] [:error] [pid 9972] [client 127.0.0.1:34926] Entering Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View::_prepareLayout
[Fri Jun 12 11:15:30.554524 2015] [:error] [pid 9972] [client 127.0.0.1:34926] Entering FKoessler_MyProduct_Block_Product_View::_prepareLayout
[Fri Jun 12 11:15:30.556209 2015] [:error] [pid 9972] [client 127.0.0.1:34926] Entering FKoessler_MyProduct_Block_Product_View::_prepareLayout
[Fri Jun 12 11:15:30.557015 2015] [:error] [pid 9972] [client 127.0.0.1:34926] Entering FKoessler_MyProduct_Block_Product_View::_prepareLayout
[Fri Jun 12 11:15:30.562598 2015] [:error] [pid 9972] [client 127.0.0.1:34926] Entering FKoessler_MyProduct_Block_Product_View::_prepareLayout
```

That's why the regular Magento canonical link gets added too. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because Magento enters the `_prepareLayout` methods of both `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View::_prepareLayout` and `FKoessler_MyProduct_Block_Product_View::_prepareLayout`.. Go figure why

So the trick is to first remove the canonical links with `$headBlock->removeItem` before adding them back with `$headBlock->addLinkRel`:

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/breadcrumbs');
$headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
if ($headBlock) {
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $title = $product->getMetaTitle();
    if ($title) {
        $headBlock->setTitle($title);
    }
    $keyword = $product->getMetaKeyword();
    $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
    if ($keyword) {
        $headBlock->setKeywords($keyword);
    } elseif ($currentCategory) {
        $headBlock->setKeywords($product->getName());
    }
    $description = $product->getMetaDescription();
    if ($description) {
        $headBlock->setDescription( ($description) );
    } else {
        $headBlock->setDescription(Mage::helper('core/string')->substr($product->getDescription(), 0, 255));
    }
    if ($this->helper('catalog/product')->canUseCanonicalTag()) {

        $params = array('_ignore_category' => true);

        /////////////////////////////////////// START WITH CANONICAL
        $cannURL = $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, $params);

        $productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        $tmpStoreCode = false;
        $tmpStoreCode =  Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();

        $expCatIdStore = false;

        switch ($tmpStoreCode) {
            case 'paris_french':
                $expCatIdStore = 2;
                break;
            case 'nimes_french':
                $expCatIdStore = 3;
                break;
            case 'niort_french':
                $expCatIdStore = 6;
                break;
        }

        if ($expCatIdStore && $productId) {
            $headBlock->removeItem('link_rel', $cannURL);
            if ($tmpStoreCode === 'paris_french') {
                $cannURL = str_replace('/paris', '', $cannURL);
                $headBlock->addLinkRel('canonical', $cannURL);
            } elseif ($tmpStoreCode === 'nimes_french') {
                $cannURL = str_replace('/nimes', '', $cannURL);
                $headBlock->addLinkRel('canonical', $cannURL);
            } elseif ($tmpStoreCode === 'niort_french') {
                $cannURL = str_replace('/niort', '', $cannURL);
                $headBlock->addLinkRel('canonical', $cannURL);
            } else {
                $headBlock->addLinkRel('canonical', $cannURL);
            }
        }
        //////////////////////////////////// END WITH CANONICAL

    }
}

return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your method, you are running `return parent::_prepareLayout()` which is running the `_prepareLayout` of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`.

Instead, since you re-implemented the method from the `catalog/product_view` block, you should call the parent's parent `_prepareLayout` function. To do that, replace that last line of your method with:

```
return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::_prepareLayout();
```

This is also so that you don't run the same code twice.
<sup>Though, a better solution may be to disable canonical URL from the configuration, and implement your own.</sup>

Comment: `class FKoessler_MyProduct_Block_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` so `return parent::_prepareLayout()` is correct, right?

Comment: also, if I disable canonical URL from the configuration, I will loose the regular canonical links on all the other pages, and I want them

Comment: Extending the abstract class works as well, but you will have issues if you need fuctionality from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`. This will happen if you added a `<rewrite>` rule in your config for that block to use yours instead.

Comment: As for your second comment, you can disable canonical urls just for products. But keep them on for categories.

Comment: I want to keep on using Magento's canonicals and modify them to always point to the main store, that's why I need to keep canonical URL enabled.